# how to read formData content type from url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i know i can get data from Url in reactjs with hook `useLocation()`and search parameter over there like :

```
 const search = useLocation().search;
  const resCode = new URLSearchParams(search).get('ResCode');
```

is possible to get formData from Url also ?

i can see payload of my data in network but how can i get these values?

[image]

when i give the callback Return url to the server , after progress that return me values with formData this parameter....
how can i read values of RefId , ResCode andSaleOrderId in reactjs ?

> that is a Post method with formData

Answer (score 2):

You can't, in the general case (since this is a `POST` or `PUT` or similar¹). The data is as the body of the request (the form submission), and not returned in the response (the new page generated in response to the form submission).² This is different from query string parameters; those are part of the URL the form is submitted to, which is the URL of the new page that's returned (if there's no redirect involved), so you can access those by looking at the URL. But not the form data.

---

¹ If it were a form submitted via `GET` or similar, the form data wouldn't be shown there in the network panel, it would be added to the URL as query string parameters.

² Unless of course the response is custom-coded to return the data, in which case you could get it from the body of the returned page, but how you did that would be specific to each page, and again the page may not include the data at all.